# How to solve recurrence $T(n) = 5T(\frac{n}{2}) + n^2\lg^2 n$

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence-relation, summation

I have tried solve the recurrence $T(n) = 5T(\frac{n}{2}) + n^2\lg^2 n$ using substitution. Apparently, it is exact for some $n$ and the order of the general solution can be found from this exact solution.

By substitution I got the following (not sure if it is correct):

$$T(n) = 5^kT(1) + \sum_{i = 0}^{k}{5^{i}\left(\frac{n}{2^{i}}\right)^{2}\lg^{2}\left(\frac{n}{2^{i}}\right)}$$

I am not sure how to proceed from this. I don't even know if this approach is correct so far. How do I solve this recurrence?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)). 
This theorem allows you to solve some recurrences of the form $T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)$.

You need to compare $n^{\log_b a}$ with $f(n)$.
In you case $n^{\log_b a} = n^{\log_2 5}$ and $f(n)=n^2 \log^2 n$.

There are different cases depending on how the above functions compare, but I am only going to discuss the one that is relevant to you (you can find more on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms))).

In your case $f(n) = O(n^{\log_b a - c})$ for some constant $c>0$.
To see this pick, e.g., $c=0.1$ and substitute to obtain:
$n^2 \log^2 n = O(n^{\log_2 5 -0.1})$, which is true since $\log_2 5 - 0.1 > 2$.

The master theorem then tells you that $T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a})$, which in your case is $T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_2 5})$.

Comment: But is this an exact solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "exact solution"? It is not an equality but since $T(n) \in \Theta(n^{\log_2 5})$ this tells you that there are two constants $c_1$ and $c_2$  with $0 \le c_1 \le c_2$ such that, for every sufficiently large value of $n$, $c_1 n^{\log_2 5} \le T(n) \le c_2 n^{\log_2 5}$.

Comment: By exact solution I mean an equality. But I suppose, this is good enough. Thank you!

Comment: I am not familiar with the master theorem, could you show how to solve this problem with it in your solution? @Steven

Comment: I have edited my answer to add mode details.

Comment: Shouldn't $f(n)$, on the first line of your edit, be $f(n) = n^2\lg^2 n$? @Steven

Comment: Yes, I fixed it. Thanks.